# Does right continuity imply only countably many discontinuities?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Does right continuity imply only countably many discontinuities? That is, if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is right continuous then does it only have countable many discontinuities?

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about it?

Comment: Yes, for the standard reason: Show that any discontinuity is a jump discontinuity. Show how this allows you to assign (injectively) an open interval to each discontinuity, and conclude.

Comment: You can also see this thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65941/if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-a-left-continuous-function-can-the-set-of-disc

Comment: Ok thanks guys.