# Approximate the integral of left-continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Assume that you have a continuous function $f:[0,t]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then it is bounded and Borel-measurable, hence integrable. And using uniform-continuity it can be proved that if you have a sequence of partitions of $[0,t]$, where for each n, $\{t_i^n\}$ is a partition of $[0,t]$, and the norm of the partition goes to 0 as n goes to infinity. Then $\Sigma_{i=0}^{N(n)-1} f(t_i^n)(t_{i+1}^n-t_i^n)$ converges to $\int_o^tf(s)ds$ as n goes to infinity.

> But what if we only assume that f is left-continuous and integrable(or
>   bounded if that has an impact on the answer?). Does it then follow that
>   we can approximate the integral by sums of the form above? Can we
>   always do this for any sequence, and do we have to take care of how we
>   choose the evaluation points in each partition?

When trying to prove this I get stuck, because I do not have the uniform continuity as I did above. Intuitively I think it should work if I instead use the sum $\Sigma_{i=1}^{N(n)} f(t_i^n)(t_{i}^n-t_{i-1}^n)$, because of the left continuity. But since I do not have uniform continuity I don't see how to show that this converges.

Any hints?

**Update**
An easier way to ask the question is this: If f is bounded and left continuous, then by DCT $\Sigma_{i=0}^{N(n)-1}f(t_i^n)(t_{i+1}^n-t_i^n)$ converges to $\int_0^tf(s)ds$ as n goes to infinity. Do we have the same type of convergence if f is not bounded, but integrable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking whether a (bounded) left-continuous function must be Cauchy integrable.

According to [If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a left continuous function can the set of discontinuous points of $f$ have positive Lebesgue measure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65941/if-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-a-left-continuous-function-can-the-set-of-disc), a left-continuous function is continuous except at countably many points.  In particular, this function is almost everywhere continuous, so it is Riemann integrable.

According to [The equivalence between Cauchy integral and Riemann integral for bounded functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326197/the-equivalence-between-cauchy-integral-and-riemann-integral-for-bounded-functio), a bounded function is Cauchy integrable iff it is Riemann integrable.

If you drop boundedness, this need not hold: an unbounded integrable left-continuous function can fail to be Cauchy integrable.  Consider the interval $[-1,1]$ and the function $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-1/2}, & x > 0 \\ 0 , & x \le 0 \end{cases}$.  For each $n$, choose a partition $\{t_i^n\}$ that contains $\frac{1}{n^4}$ and $\frac{1}{n^4} + \frac{1}{n}$ as successive points, filling it out with other points less than $\frac{1}{n}$ apart.  Then the left-endpoint Riemann sum using this partition is at least $n$, so the sums diverge.  Using right endpoints doesn't help either; in that case use $\frac{1}{n^4} - \frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^4}$ as successive points.

Comment: Thank you, does this mean that it is true if we assume left-continuous and bounded, but it may not hold if it is not bounded?

Comment: @user119615: See edit.